# Calculate Median on Sql

Tags: sql-server

I am very new to SQL. I am trying to use the code below and it keeps giving me the following error -

> Msg The ORDER BY clause is invalid in
>   views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table
>   expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is
>   also specified.
>
> Incorrect syntax near '2'.

Please can someone help - where am I going wrong?

I am just trying to calculate median.

Could someone please suggest amendment to this code as I have picked up someone else's work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    TOP (100) PERCENT Name, Sales Median
FROM
    (SELECT 
         a1.Name, a1.Sales, COUNT(a1.Sales) Rank
     FROM          
         PSE.vw_EM_Data a1, PSE.vw_EM_Data a2
     WHERE      
         a1.Sales < a2.Sales OR
         (a1.Sales = a2.Sales AND a1.Name <= a2.Name)
     GROUP BY 
         a1.Name, a1.Sales
     ORDER BY 
         a1.Sales DESC) a3
WHERE 
    Rank = (SELECT (COUNT(*) + 1) DIV 2 FROM Total_Sales);
WHERE     
    (Name LIKE 'John%') 
    AND (DISPOSAL = '1') 
    AND (DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-04-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-03-30 00:00:00', 102))
```

Comment: Please, format you query as code sample - makes it readable.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is from the order by with in the subselect `a3`

Why not rather have a look at using [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to point out:

1) I would never use the "old-style" JOIN syntax that you use in your inner `SELECT` - it can easily lead to unwanted cartesian products - as it does in your case (though I'm not sure whether that's wanted or not....)

So instead of:

```
FROM          
   PSE.vw_EM_Data a1, PSE.vw_EM_Data a2
```

I would recommend to use the proper ANSI JOIN syntax

```
FROM          
   PSE.vw_EM_Data a1  
INNER JOIN           -- or possibly: LEFT OUTER JOIN or even FULL OUTER JOIN
   PSE.vw_EM_Data a2 ON a1.Sales = a2.Sales
```

which makes it much clearer what it is you really want, and avoids any unnecessary problems.

2) In your second `WHERE` clause, you first of all don't need all those parenthesis, really - and most of all, you definitely shouldn't be converting a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column into a string to then compare it - so instead of this:

```
WHERE     
    (Name LIKE 'John%') 
    AND (DISPOSAL = '1') 
    AND (DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2010-04-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-03-30 00:00:00', 102))
```

use this instead:

```
WHERE     
    Name LIKE 'John%'
    AND DISPOSAL = '1'
    AND [DATE] BETWEEN '2010-04-01T00:00:00' AND '2011-03-30T00:00:00'
```

and I would also try to avoid calling a column by a name that's a keyword in SQL like `DATE` - you'll have to use square brackets around it to make things clear to SQL Server.